# add a tag inside template literals

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

### Is it possible to add a tag in template literals that will be used to fill in tags in ReactJS? example at previewDiscrption

```
const data = {
    activeProjectId: null,
    modalShow: false,
    projectsFlipped: false,
    menuShow: false,
    projects: [
        {
            id: 'project-title-0',
            title: 'Hello there!'.toUpperCase(),
            image: project11,
            medium: 'React, 3.js, SCSS, HTML',
            previewDescription:
                `This portfolio site is built on React,  uses Three.js for the flying star animations, and  a mix of CSS transforms and vanilla JS scrolling for the page transitions.  For the best effect, view while listening to` +
                (
                    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qap5aO4i9A">
                        LoFi music
                    </a>
                ) +
                `.`,
            link: 'https://github.com/justanothergoonie/codys-portfolioo',
            gitLink: 'https://github.com/justanothergoonie/codys-portfolioo',
        },
```

Comment: Sure. Where you are trying to render this string will decide if it works or not. Can you post a more comprehensive code example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and check https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: @DrewReese im trying to render it out to a component, i could possibly create a code example tomorrow, this my second react project, i could also provide the github link

Comment: I doesn't need to be anything fancy, just a enough of an example to see what your code is doing and what may be the issue if there is one. It sort of sounds like you are just asking if it's possible and haven't necessarily tried anything yet. If so, then please do try something and get back to us with a MRE if you hit any snags. The link to your repo is fine, but you should still include the code example for future readers.

Comment: @DrewReese heard that, ive pretty much done whats shown in the code block above and i got back [object Object] where i expect my tag to be

Comment: You can. You just need to enclose the entire string with literals and use `${}` to enclose the JSX part.

 `Preview description:\`This portfolio site is built on React, 
uses Three.js for the flying star animations, and 
a mix of CSS transforms and vanilla JS scrolling for the page transitions. 
For the best effect, view while listening to
${(
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qap5aO4i9A">
    LoFi music
</a>
)} .\``

Comment: Why would you want to use JSX when you want to have the literal tag in your string? Then just put the characters in the string literal. I don't get really what the issue can be. What is wrong with `"this is my tag: <span>tag</span>"`?

Comment: @DhanaD. this just returns the same [object Object] in the html

Comment: @trincot because im using an array of object data to fill in components. so if i were to add  "this is my tag: <span>tag</span>" to the component all 12 of my projects get that tag

Comment: Then your question is not clear. Please update your question to give such example. I don't see any array of objects there.

Comment: @trincot good point, thank you, is that better?

Comment: I still don't get why it could not be `previewDescription: \`This portfolio... <a href=""></a>\`,` ... so without JSX notation.

Comment: Agreed. The string should just contain the HTML, then the entire string can be processed as HTML.

Comment: previewDescription:
    `This portfolio site is built on React,  uses Three.js for the flying star animations, and  a mix of CSS transforms and vanilla JS scrolling for the page transitions.  For the best effect, view while listening to
    
     <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qap5aO4i9A">
      LoFi music
     </a>
     
    .`                                                            like this?

Comment: Yes, then you can pass that into an element using a special prop... see my first comment.

Comment: @DrewReese when i do that, it puts "<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qap5aO4i9A">       LoFi music      </a> " on the page not just 'Lofi Music' as a link

Comment: Check this running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/add-a-tag-inside-template-literals-xsxjy).

Answer (score 0):

You’re looking for [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml).

```
const stringContainingHtml = "here is the <b>html</b> string"
const jsxElement = <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: stringContainingHtml }}/>
```

Comment: wouldnt that be used in a specific place like a component and not in a set of data being passed to the componenents?

Comment: Yes - if your components need to render HTML data, this is how they do it. The data is just a string.